# Push object to array of array - react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to add a new object in the array of items, which is located in a particular shop, but redux isn't re-rendering. I have tried the spread and concat method, as the push function is not recommended, but it isn't working.

```
const initialState ={
  stores: []
}
```

// the store after the data is fetched looks like this:

```
stores: [
  {
    name: "iPhone store", 
    id: 12345, 
    items: [
      {id: 1233, name: "iPhone 7"}
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to add a new item in a particular store and the reducer looks like this:

```
const store_new_item = (state, action) => {
  // not re-rendering
  let stores = [...state.stores];
  const index = stores.findIndex((a) => a._id === action.storeid);

  stores[index] = {
    ...stores[index],
    items: stores[index].items.concat({ ...action.item, _id: nanoid() }),
  };

  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    stores: stores,
  };
};
```

Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

```
stores[index] = {
    ...stores[index],
    items: [...stores[index].items, action.item],
  };
```

Comment: does any of those methods actually changes the state?

Comment: Got the problem, I forgot that I was passing the items as props from a component which renders tab navigation, so it wouldn't re-render as it acts like a initialState